# What is the route of a re- rendered page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes

I have a controller action that: when information is entered incorrectly causes the form to be re -rendered.

```
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
        log_in @user
        flash[:success] = "You have successfully created your account"
        redirect_to app_path
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

I also have a sidebar, that does not show on the login page using a conditional statement...

```
<% if current_page?(login_path) 

<% else %>
<%= render 'layouts/sidebar' %>
<% end %>
```

Thats working fine... the problem is that if a user enters data incorrectly the login form is re-rendered with an error message and the sidebar then appears, when it should not.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because when the error is raised it's rendering the `create` action in your controller, which is not the same as the named route called `login_path`.

Instead, use something like the following snippet in your view:

```
<% unless params[:controller] == 'sessions' %>
  <%= render 'layouts/sidebar' %>
<% end %>
```

(obviously change 'sessions' to the name of your controller).

Comment: Ha thats so weird... I had just figured out the problem by installing a debug dump... I see the create action there. Didn't know how to fix it though so thank you very much! I can move on at last.